# Why can any be assigned to every type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, nullable

This is a philosophical question about the type structure in TypeScript.

Let's take look at the following short snippet ([available as a playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQARgBQEoBcqDOcATglAOaoDeoqtqAbgIZGoAeejUAnqgLypQIAGyEBuGnSIBTOBCJpW4kAF9QoGCkKoAtlwDKxUhX6YsSgPTmd+w+VQALRvlRwuABykFbZUJYFI4LxI7AB9UTi4AGn9AwmCKMOgAEykwUikk6KgAoKNUMMERXyt8JFQASVQpVg94VARAuDLpRhEeACNPRlzydU0kISkAOiEkMgxdA3iRqXI4ezNi1ABaAD5UABV3KQBRIiIkIjxCoXrnbMDOVCR2gCspOowpJiEIRkQ7Se8ZuYW1ECAA)).

```
function f(): string {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return 'a real string';
    }
    var x: any = null;
    // Why does this type check?
    return x;
}

const myString = f();
// myString has type string
// not string | any, not string | undefined, not string | null
// so I expect it to really be a string
console.log(myString.length);
// -> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating myString.length)
```

In short, my question is why does this example compile with all possible strictness flags enabled?

The documentation on `any` states that `any` is used to "describe the type of variables that we do not know". For this reason, it makes sense that all types can be *assigned to* `any`, however, why can `any` be assigned to all other types?

By its very nature, objects with type `any` have unknown properties, so why can they be marshaled into other types (like `string`) with no warning? Does this not defeat the purpose of explicitly tagging things with types when we know the compiler is not enforcing their contents?

For example, let's say that I want to define a function that unequivocally returns a `string` (not `null`, not `undefined`, not `number`, but exactly `string`). Is there a way to get the TypeScript compiler to enforce that every codepath that returns from that function returns a string? My preconception is that the example above *should* be doing that, and that we should see an error like `any is not assignable to type string`, but we do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The documentation on any states that any is used to "describe the type of variables that we do not know"

Since TypeScript 3.0, you should use [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) to describe such types instead.

`any` is an artifact from the past, and you shouldn't be using it except for rare edge cases where you cannot use `unknown`. There are a few (arcane) ones.

**Solution**

```
function f(): string {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return 'a real string';
    }
    var x: unknown = null;
    return x; // Compile-time error: "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)"
}
```

Comment: This is excellent and just what I was looking for. Thank you. It is interesting that the `unknown` type is not documented at all in the current handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html
You have to specifically find the link to the 3.0 release notes.

Comment: The TypeScript language specification is a bit of a mess. The runtime semantics are not specified *at all*, it is simply assumed that you have ECMA-262 memorized. The syntax is not specified, except by example. The type system is partially specified in the handbook, partially in changelogs, partially in GitHub Issues.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That is kind of a shame. In my programming languages course in university, it was shown that formality and a focus on specifications was critical to creating sound systems. I guess we must be that change we want to see in the world and submit a patch to the documentation.